# Скрипт, прикрепить файл к pdf (windows)

Tags: javascript, windows, bat, pdf, doc

Подскажите решение, нужно .doc файл конвертировать в pdf, а к нему прикрепить исходный .doc.
Я нашёл как сконвертировать doc в pdf с помощью  word и activex, работает из батника. Но не могу прикрепить к pdf, adobe acrobat activex компоненты не позволяют или я не нашёл как.

Comment: Скорее всего, компоненты  Adobe Acrobat могут это сделать, внимательно прочтите документацию. Но если один инструмент не помог, его меняют на другой. Например: PDFtools;Coherent PDF tools;PDFtk Pro; Prince. Лишь последний из списка бесплатен для некоммерческого использования. Я думаю Вам просто нужно поискать информацию поглубже.

Comment: Читал к акробату документацию из javascript можно, но не пойму как в батнике использовать . Взял pdftk.